# How to fix JavaScript SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in my JavaScript file:

```
  input = '<input id="ytRequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="hidden" value="" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" />
    <input class="form-control" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" id="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="file" />
<div class="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12 fileprogress" style="display: none"><div class="filename">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <strong></strong>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1"
                     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="percent">0</span>%
                         </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info_danger_text"><p></p></div>
        </div>
        ';
```

But, when I run my web application, It is showing Uncaught `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like a missing `'` at the end of the string

Comment: missing something maybe `'` at the end?

Comment: You can not do multiline strings in JS like that. Either use template strings or escape the line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that there are line breaks in your "String". In JavaScript if you want to assign string to a variable which contains line breaks you should use "`\`" at the end of the line.
The following is the corrected code.

```
input = '<input id="ytRequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="hidden" value="" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" />\
<input class="form-control" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" id="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="file" />\
<div class="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12 fileprogress" style="display: none">'
```

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiline strings only in ES6. To do this you have to use backtick character instead of quote.

See [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the string variable in only one line. If you want to write it in multiple lines you can do it by:

1. Declaring it concatenating each line with +

   ```js
       input = '<input id="ytRequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="hidden" value="" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" />' +
           '<input class="form-control" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" id="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="file" />' +
       '<div class="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12 fileprogress" style="display: none">';
   ```
2. Using the Template literals feature https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/

```js
input = `<input id="ytRequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="hidden" value="" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" />
            <input class="form-control" name="RequirementsForm[additional][f__12][]" id="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12" type="file" />
        <div class="RequirementsForm_additional_f__12 fileprogress" style="display: none">`;
```